# jquery Sliding effect for table elements

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, rotation, autorotate

Currently, I'm doing up an auto-scroll function for a list on my site.

However, after the first item in the list disappears, the second one kinds of 'jump in to position' of the first item. What i want to know if it is possible to make the second item slide in to position in jquery and how can i do it? The following is the javascript code and html. Thanks for any help in advance.

Javascript:

```
    <script>
    var $target=$("tr.latest_arr td.rotate:first");
    $target.animate({
        marginLeft: -200,
        opacity: 0,
    }, function(){
        $target.css({
            marginLeft: 200
        }).appendTo('tr.latest_arr').animate({
            marginLeft: 0,
            opacity: 1
        })
    });
},5000);
    </script>
```

HTML(Sample) generated:

```
 <table>  
    <tr class="latest_arr">
       <td class="rotate" style="float:left;width:200px">Item 1</td>
       <td class="rotate" style="float:left;width:200px">Item 2</td>
       <td class="rotate" style="float:left;width:200px">Item 3</td>
       <td class="rotate" style="float:left;width:200px">Item 4</td>
       <td class="rotate" style="float:left;width:200px">Item 5</td>
            ...
            ...
            ...
    </tr>
 </table>
```

I was able to do this for a list but it changes when i switched the tags to table elements.

This is what i'm facing now:

http://jsfiddle.net/fxHAe/

This is what i'm looking for but in table form:

http://jsbin.com/welcome/53677

Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this in table form?

Comment: I need it so all items in the list stay in the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Results are expected!,
I would do it this way

```
    var ad_refresh=setInterval(function(){
    var $target=$("ul.latest_arr li.rotate:first");
    $target.animate({
        marginLeft: -200,
        opacity: 0,
    }, function(){
        $target.css({
            marginLeft: 200
        }).appendTo('ul.latest_arr').animate({
            marginLeft: 0,
            opacity: 1
        })
    });
},1000);​

<ul class="latest_arr">
    <li class="rotate">foo1</li>
    <li class="rotate">foo2</li>
    <li class="rotate">foo3</li>
    <li class="rotate">foo4</li>
    <li class="rotate">foo5</li>
</ul>

        <style type="text/css">
         li{float:left}
        </style>​
```

results [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fxHAe/1/) 
And ofcourse changing ul css width as you want will work better for your case

Comment: Hi. Yes. but i need it in table form so that my elements stay in the same height.

Comment: you can add fixed height to li with display:block

Comment: ooh.sorry. Maybe i said it wrongly. Let me rephrase. I want the elements to maintain the same height as the tallest element in the list.